# Avoid Duplicates of Unique Key Within INSERT Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query that looks like this:

`INSERT INTO beer(name, type, alcohol_by_volume, description, image_url) VALUES('{$name}', {$type}, '{$alcohol_by_volume}', '{$description}', '{$image_url}')`

The only problem is that name is a unique value, which means if I ever run into duplicates, I get an error like this:

```
Error storing beer data: Duplicate entry 'Hocus Pocus' for key 2
```

Is there a way to ensure that the SQL query does not attempt to add a unique value that already exists without running a `SELECT` query for the entire database?

Comment: +1 clear and easy to understand your question

Comment: What do you want to happen if the unique value already exists? Overwrite the existing data? Or change the _name_ to come up with something unique automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could of course use INSERT IGNORE INTO, like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO beer(name, type, alcohol_by_volume, description, image_url) VALUES('{$name}', {$type}, '{$alcohol_by_volume}', '{$description}', '{$image_url}')
```

You could use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` as well, but if you just don't want to add a row `INSERT IGNORE INTO` is a better choice. `ON DUPLICATE KEY` is better suited if you want to do something more specific when there are a duplicate.

If you decide to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` - avoid using this clause on tables with multiple unique indexes. If you have a table with multiple unique indexes `ON DUPLICATE KEY`-clause could be giving unexpected results (You really don't have 100% control what's going to happen)

**Example:** - this row below only updates ONE row (if type is 1 and alcohol_by_volume 1 (and both columns are unique indexes))

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE beer SET type=3 WHERE type=1 or alcohol_by_volume=1
```

To sum it up:

`ON DUPLICATE KEY` just does the work without warnings or errors when there are duplicates.

`INSERT IGNORE INTO` throws a warning when there are duplicates, but besides from that just ignore to insert the duplicate into the database.

Answer (score 6):

As it just so happens, there is a way in MySQL by using [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). This is available since MySQL 4.1

```
INSERT INTO beer(name, type, alcohol_by_volume, description, image_url)
  VALUES('{$name}', {$type}, '{$alcohol_by_volume}', '{$description}',
  '{$image_url}')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE type=type;
```

You could also use [`INSERT IGNORE INTO...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html) as an alternative, but the statement would still throw a warning (albeit, instead of an error).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. You can use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause of mysql `INSERT` statement. The syntax is explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO beer(name, type, alcohol_by_volume, ...) 
  VALUES('{$name}', {$type}, '{$alcohol_by_volume}', ...)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
     type={$type}, alcohol_by_volume = '{$alcohol_by_volume}', ... ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by first selecting the name from the database, and if the result of the query is not null (zero records), then the name already exists, and you have to get another name.

Comment: The only problem is if a record is inserted in the period of time between the SELECT and the INSERT

Comment: Then an "ON DUPLICATE" could help, if it is feasible that the existing row is updated of course...

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply - your code needs to figure out what it wants to do if something's trying to insert a duplicate name.  As such, what you need to do first is run a select statement:

```
 SELECT * FROM beer WHERE name='{$name}'
```

And then run an 'if' statement off of that to determine if you got a result.

if results = 0, then go ahead and run your insert.
Else ... whatever you want to do.  Throw an error back to the user?  Modify the database in a different way?  Completely ignore it?  How is this insert statement coming about?  A mass update from a file?  User input from a web page?

The way you're reaching this insert statement, and how it should affect your work flow, should determine exactly how you're handling that 'else'.  But you should definitely handle it.

But just make sure that the select and insert statements are in a transaction together so that other folks coming in to do the same sort of stuff isn't an issue.

Comment: The question was if OP could do insertion and checking without using select-statements.

Comment: Yes, but none of the other solutions give feedback.  The feedback from the program is important ... and with very little detail on what the overall scenario entails, I thought it important to stress that.

Comment: "None of the other solutions give feedback" How on earth do you mean? You say that feedback from program is important. Of course it - if it's necessary. But when the db-engine could be used, it SHOULD be used. I mean - when there are functions to handle some situations like this and there a functions in MySQL to handle it, why not use them? There are no reason in at all as I see it.

Comment: Ah... fundamental difference in programming philosophy.  I could answer your questions, but this isn't supposed to be a chat, so I'm going to decline.

Comment: Ok, I guess it's good that everyone doesn't think likewise. It would have been a boring planet then :-)